# Vertical Progress Bar with milestones

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, progress-bar

I'm trying to make something like this:
[image]

I need to be able to pass in how high the bar should fill up (ie the percentage full I'd like it to be).

Vuetify offers lots of horizontal progress bars (seen here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-linear/) but I can't find any vertical ones. I was thinking if I could rotate one of the horizontal ones then I could add circles that fill up when each milestone is hit. So is there any way of rotating a horizontal progress bar or is there another simpler solution to this using HTML, CSS and JS?

Comment: I personally get an uncomfortable feeling when I have to think about frameworks and Vue. If one had to make one with HTML, CSS and JS 'as is' it would be clear, but that is jut me, I guess. I was just about to say, rotate the container and counter rotate the numbers, but that is rather hacky. If this thing has parts with a fixed height, then inside, height 100% will work, or preferrably use `transform: scaleY(1)` (from 0) or something of that sort, but I don't think this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @roye7777777, how would you do it in HTML, CSS and JS?